nullable datetime cannot map through extension method
I encounter a problem when I try to map DateTime? to string,
if source value is null, it will not step in extension method,
do anyone know why?
and I try automapper 10.0 it's normal!
version
Automapper 11.0
.Net6
below is my source code
void Main()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Date, 
                  opt =>opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.ToCommon()));
               
        });

    IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var source = new Source { Date = null };
    var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);

    Console.WriteLine(destination.Date);
}


public static class Temp
{
    public static string ToCommon(this DateTime? dateTime)
    {
        if (dateTime is null)
            return "something";

        return dateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    }
}

public class Source
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
}

I expect result should be return "something" ,but return null

This behavior of MapFrom is discussed here.
Simply put, AutoMapper automatically checks for null and does not execute MapFrom when value is null.

AutoMapper for code safety will check the null and won't execute and call a method on null objects. As @dpant mentioned in the comment you can check this issue on the GitHub: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2409
But I found a trick to make it work:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.Date, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Date.ToCommon() ?? ""));
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var sourceDateNull = new Source { Date = null };
var destinationDateNull = mapper.Map<Destination>(sourceDateNull);

Assert.Equal("something", destinationDateNull.Date);


By above mapping your extension method gets called and will replace something for null datetimes.
